Stone-Weierstrass and constant functions
In Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Gerald Folland, (2nd edition, page 141, Corollary 4.50), we find the following statement of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ that separates points. If there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ for all $f \in \mathcal B$, then $\mathcal B$ is dense in $\{f \in C(X,\mathbb R) : f(x_0) = 0\}$. Otherwise, $\mathcal B$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb R)$.

Now consider the familiar problem where $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space with dense subset $\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$. We wish to show that $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is separable.
For $i=1,2,\dots$, define $f_i(x) = d(x,p_i)$. It is easy to show that each $f_i$ is continuous, and the family $\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}$ separates points because if $x \ne y$ then we can find some $p_i$ which is closer to $x$ than $y$, and hence $f_i(x) \ne f_i(y)$.
So far so good. Now let $\mathcal B$ be the subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb R)$ consisting of all $\mathbb Q$-linear combinations of finite products of the $f_i$ and the constant function $\mathbf 1$. It follows from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem and the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ that $\mathcal B$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb R)$. Since $\mathcal B$ is countable, it follows that $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is separable.
My question is: Why do we need to explicitly include $\mathbf 1$?
Let $\mathcal B'$ be the subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb R)$ consisting of all $\mathbb Q$-linear combinations of finite products of the $f_i$. Remembering Folland's statement above, it is clear that there can be no $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ for all $f \in \mathcal B'$, since $f_i(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = p_i$. Hence $\mathcal B'$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb R)$.
The arguments I've seen online for this problem typically use $\mathcal B$, so I fear I may be missing something.
Thanks in advance!

I suppose, the inclusion of $\mathbf 1$ just allows to skip a step in the proof. So, why not?

If that is the only reason, great! I just wasn't sure if I was missing something. The subalgebra generated by ${f_i}$ obviously cannot share a root.

I don't see any gaps in the proof using $\mathcal B'$. But, personally, I find the proof that uses $\mathcal B$ a bit clearer due to the presense of $\mathbf 1$.

Yes, I think a more common statement of Stone-Weierstrass seems to simply require that $\mathcal B$ contain a nonzero constant function.

If $X$ only has one point, then the only function you define is the zero function.

Thank you so much for this clarification!
